# What's the term of manage and expost web applications like SharePoint

Tags: terminology, platform

Ruffly Speaking, I want to know the name of the feature which Microsoft SharePoint provides that the ablility to manage many web applications and expose them as web parts.

I'll try to explane more, from wikipedia:

> Microsoft  SharePoint is a software platform provides collaboration, Web content management, documents management, enterprise search, Web 2.0 features, and many other features under a single platform.

What I understand from that that it's a collection of features provided in a single system, I would like to search about a software platform similar to SharePoint able to manage many web applications and expose them or provides them as web parts but I don't know the search keywords which I have to look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the keyword “Portal”.